# Troubleshooting arguments - Channel ID's

Tags: discord.py, nextcord, pycord

```
@client.slash_command(name = 'announce', description = 'Makes XYZ announcement in your announcements channel')
@application_checks.has_guild_permissions(moderate_members=True)
async def announce(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, channel: nextcord.TextChannel, *, msg):
    await channel.send(f'{msg}')
```

I keep receiving a typehint error which is relevant to SlashOptions. I am just trying to send the message into the specified channel defined by the channel argument. Why is it error out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.slash_command(name = 'announce', description = 'Makes XYZ announcement in your announcements channel')
@application_checks.has_guild_permissions(moderate_members=True)
async def announce(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, channel: nextcord.TextChannel, *, msg):
    channel_id = channel.id
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(f'{msg}')
```

So to answer my own question I went back and was looking at previous code I had written and realized I never specified where I was trying to send the message even though the channel was an "argument"

To fix this I realized that I needed to specify the channel the user was inputting by utilizing:

```
#Creates a variable to collect channel: nextcord.TextChannel

    channel_id = channel.id

# Now specifying the channel to send it to by grabbing the channel id of the requested channel.

    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
```

This more or less became less Slash Option help and more of an understanding command arguments. Never give up folks! You'll get there eventually.